Use Color and Gradient as fill conditionally?
I have the following code:
struct TestContainer: View {
    @State var useGradient = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black
            
            Button {
                
                
            } label: {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: .infinity)
                    .fill(useGradient ? buttonGradient() as! Color : Color.green)
                    .overlay {
                        Text("Done")
                            .font(.system(size: 17, weight: .semibold))
                            .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        
                    }
                    .cornerRadius(.infinity)
                
            }
            .frame(height: 44)
            .padding(.horizontal, 40)
            
        }
    }
    
    private func buttonGradient() -> some View {
        
        return LinearGradient(
            stops: [
                Gradient.Stop(color: Color(red: 0.1, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2), location: 0.00),
                Gradient.Stop(color: Color(red: 0.1, green: 0.3, blue: 0), location: 1.00),
            ],
            startPoint: UnitPoint(x: 0, y: 1),
            endPoint: UnitPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
            )
    }
}

At times I get:

Could not cast value of type 'SwiftUI.LinearGradient' (0x1f2bf7980) to 'SwiftUI.Color' (0x1f2c1b688).

How can I make this work where depending on the useGradient state the fill changes?

What about just providing a gradient with one stop when you just want a solid color?

yes, that is what I just did. I guess that's the easier way out of this one... LinearGradient(
gradient: Gradient(colors: [color, color]),
startPoint: .topLeading,
endPoint: .bottomTrailing
)

If the colors in the gradient are always fully opaque then you could use the gradient as the FillStyle and apply the other color in the background. Then set the opacity of the gradient conditionally.

The suggestions in the comments provide a couple of ways of doing this.
Another way would be to use a generic function that receives a ShapeStyle as parameter. This requires that the gradient is delivered as some ShapeStyle instead of as some View:
struct TestContainer: View {
    @State var useGradient = false

    private func buttonLabel<F: ShapeStyle>(fillStyle: F) -> some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: .infinity)
            .fill(fillStyle)
            .overlay {
                Text("Done")
                    .font(.system(size: 17, weight: .semibold))
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
            }
            .cornerRadius(.infinity)
    }

    private var buttonGradient: some ShapeStyle {
        LinearGradient(
            stops: [
                Gradient.Stop(color: Color(red: 0.1, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2), location: 0.00),
                Gradient.Stop(color: Color(red: 0.1, green: 0.3, blue: 0), location: 1.00),
            ],
            startPoint: UnitPoint(x: 0, y: 1),
            endPoint: UnitPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black

            Button {
                useGradient.toggle()
            } label: {
                if useGradient {
                    buttonLabel(fillStyle: buttonGradient)
                } else {
                    buttonLabel(fillStyle: .green)
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 44)
            .padding(.horizontal, 40)
        }
    }
}


A LinearGradient cannot be cast to a Color. Their common ancestor is the ShapeStyle protocol.
As you need to return a single type in the .fill() method, you’ll have to type erase both Color and LinearGradient to a single style, which you can do with AnyShapeStyle:
.fill(useGradient ? AnyShapeStyle(buttonGradient()) : AnyShapeStyle(Color.green))

However you should return some ShapeStyle instead of some View from buttonGradient().
